# how can I create a table for another schema owner in hsql

Tags: spring-batch, hsqldb

I am writing test cases for a Spring batch application.   I need to setup an HSQL database that mirrors a remote mainframe db2 database so I can run my tests quickly.

I have to setup the db table in such as way that the following SQL statement will succeed:

```
SELECT PROJ_TYP, SYS_CD, ... FROM CMNREF.CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V WITH UR
```

I believe the CMNREF above is the Schema owner.   How can I create that table and schema in HSQL db so this SELECT will work?

*Update*:
Doing some research on the topic [here](http://ihewiki.wustl.edu/wiki/images/e/ea/HSQL.pdf), I've learned that I need to do the following:
1)  Use the SA default user to create new user CMNREF
2)  Grant some ROLES to user CMNREF (i.e. SELECT)

However, I also noticed that the default user SA has the DBA role, which means it can do anything on that database.... so I wonder if I even need to bother with creating the 1 and 2  above....

My Test Case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/load-BMS-data-job-launcher-context.xml" })
public class SimpleJobLaunchFunctionalTests {

@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherUtils;

@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
@Autowired
private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplate;

@Qualifier("jdbcTemplateBMS")
@Autowired
private JdbcOperations jdbcTemplateBMS;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    jdbcTemplateBMS.update("DELETE from CMNREF.CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V");
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE from SHADOW_BMS");
 // jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE from CMNREF.CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());

    // Insert one test data record
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO CMNREF.CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V(PROJ_TYP_CD, SYS_CD, STAT_CK_CD, EXTRNL_KEY_CD, EXTRNL_SYS_CD, CNTRCT_NUM, PROJ_NUM, CNTRCT_LINE_ITM, CUST_NUM, CUST_CNTL_NUM, CUST_NM, CHRG_CD, PRDCT_ID, BILNG_CRNCY_CD, BILNG_ISO_CRNCY_CD, BILNG_CRNCY_DCM_NUM, CFTS_CRNCY_EXCH_RT, CFTS_CRNCY_EXCH_RT_EXPIR_DT, CHRG_CRNCY_CD, CHRG_ISO_CRNCY_CD, CTRY_CD, CMPNY_CD, OFFERING_CD, CNTL_GRP_CD, ORIG_CTRY_CD, ORIG_CMPNY_CD, ORIG_LOC_CD, NOTES_ID, INET_ID, CFTS_GBI_IND, CFTS_CHRG_TYP_CD, CFTS_SPCL_HNDL_CD, CC_PMT_METH_IND, STAT_CD, REFRESH_TMS) VALUES('PROJT1', 'SCD', 'STC', 'EXTKEY','EXTSYSCODE', 'CTR923','PROJN293', 23, 'CNUM32', 'CN', 'NAME THIS CUST', 'CHCD', '2903-920','BCD', 'BIC', 23, 1.345, '2017-01-23','CCC', 'CIC', 'CCD', 'IBM', '9203L-98', 'CTLGRP', 'USA', 'IBM001', 'OLC', 'me@us.ibm.com', 'ME/US/IBM/COM', 'G', 'T', 'H', 'P', 'OPEN', '2016-01-02 19:29:23.271' )");

}
```

My DB Script is there:

```
CREATE USER CMNREF PASSWORD 'pw';
CREATE SCHEMA CMNREF AUTHORIZATION DBA;

ALTER USER CMNREF SET INITIAL SCHEMA CMNREF;

SET SCHEMA CMNREF;

CREATE TABLE CMNREF.CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V  (
     PROJ_TYP_CD         VARCHAR(10),                 
     SYS_CD              VARCHAR(3),                  
     STAT_CK_CD          VARCHAR(12),                  
     EXTRNL_KEY_CD       VARCHAR(36),                  
     EXTRNL_SYS_CD       VARCHAR(10),                  
     CNTRCT_NUM          VARCHAR(15),                 
     PROJ_NUM            VARCHAR(8),                 
     CNTRCT_LINE_ITM     INTEGER,              
     CUST_NUM            VARCHAR(8),                
     CUST_CNTL_NUM       VARCHAR(2),                 
     CUST_NM             VARCHAR(35),               
     CHRG_CD             VARCHAR(4),                        
     PRDCT_ID            VARCHAR(15),               
     BILNG_CRNCY_CD      VARCHAR(3),                 
     BILNG_ISO_CRNCY_CD  VARCHAR(3),             
     BILNG_CRNCY_DCM_NUM SMALLINT,           
     CFTS_CRNCY_EXCH_RT  DECIMAL,           
     CFTS_CRNCY_EXCH_RT_EXPIR_DT   DATE,
     CHRG_CRNCY_CD       VARCHAR(3),                 
     CHRG_ISO_CRNCY_CD   VARCHAR(3),              
     CTRY_CD             VARCHAR(3),                
     CMPNY_CD            VARCHAR(10),                      
     OFFERING_CD         VARCHAR(8),                   
     CNTL_GRP_CD         VARCHAR(8),                  
     ORIG_CTRY_CD        VARCHAR(3),          
     ORIG_CMPNY_CD       VARCHAR(10),                
     ORIG_LOC_CD         VARCHAR(3),                   
     NOTES_ID            VARCHAR(100),          
     INET_ID             VARCHAR(100),          
     CFTS_GBI_IND        VARCHAR(1),          
     CFTS_CHRG_TYP_CD    VARCHAR(1),               
     CFTS_SPCL_HNDL_CD   VARCHAR(1),
     CC_PMT_METH_IND     VARCHAR(1),               
     STAT_CD             VARCHAR(12),          
     REFRESH_TMS         TIMESTAMP  
) ;
```

My DataSources are defined here:

```
    <!--  Initialise the database before every test case: -->
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.drop.script}"/>
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}"/>
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.business.schema.script}"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<!-- Initialize the mock BMS database  -->
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="BMSdataSource" ignore-failures="DROPS">
    <jdbc:script location="${bmsmock.business.schema.script}"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${batch.jdbc.pool.size}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${batch.jdbc.validationQuery}"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="BMSdataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${bmsmock.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${bmsmock.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${bmsmock.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${bmsmock.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${bmsmock.jdbc.pool.size}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${bmsmock.jdbc.validationQuery}"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${bmsmock.jdbc.testWhileIdle}"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Set up or detect a System property called "ENVIRONMENT" used to construct a properties file on the classpath.  The default is "hsql".  -->
<bean id="environment"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.SystemPropertyInitializer">
    <property name="defaultValue" value="hsql"/>
    <property name="keyName" value="ENVIRONMENT"/>
</bean>

<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    depends-on="environment">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT}.properties" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

My HSQLDB Properties are below:

batch.jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.enforce_strict_size=true;hsqldb.tx=mvcc
batch.jdbc.user=sa
batch.jdbc.password=
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql
batch.business.schema.script=classpath:/db/custom-db-assets.sql
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.HsqlMaxValueIncrementer
batch.database.incrementer.parent=columnIncrementerParent
batch.lob.handler.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler
batch.jdbc.pool.size=6
batch.grid.size=6
batch.verify.cursor.position=true
batch.isolationlevel=ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
batch.data.source.init=true
batch.table.prefix=BATCH_

bmsmock.jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
bmsmock.jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testbms;sql.enforce_strict_size=true;hsqldb.tx=mvcc
bmsmock.jdbc.user=SA
bmsmock.jdbc.password=
bmsmock.jdbc.pool.size=6
bmsmock.jdbc.testWhileIdle=false
bmsmock.jdbc.validationQuery=
bmsmock.business.schema.script=db/mock-bms-tables.sql
```

Comment: Some research above....

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use a different user without the DBA role.

In HSQLDB a user and a schema are separate concepts, with no automatic schema per user. What you have done is fine. Alternatively you can

```
CREATE USER CMNREF PASSWORD 'pw'
CREATE SCHEMA CMNREF AUTHORIZATION CMNREF
```

With the above, the CMNREF user owns a schema of the same name. It can execute all statements in its own schema.

update: In your settings the SA user is used for all the operations. You need to run the user creation section of the DB script you quoted with the user SA, then run the tests with the user CMNREF.

Comment: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V(PROJ_TYP_CD...  'ME/US/IBM/COM', 'G', 'T', 'H', 'P', 'OPEN', '2016-01-02 19:29:23.271' )]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V

Comment: I have launched the HSQL mgr like this:
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing
I can run all of the commands in there and I can insert and select data... why not in the SpringJdbcTemplate?

Comment: Use exactly the same connection URL in the DBManager and Spring to get the same behaviour.

Comment: I did.... precisely the same.... that's what's so frustrating.   I don't know what's different.   The only thing mysterious I see is that my SQL that I'm calling is like this:  "INSERT INTO CMNREF.CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V(PROJ_TYP_... )" and the error reads:  user lacks privilege or object not found: CNTRCT_EXTRNL_KEY_REF_V, without the schema qualifier?!

Comment: There's also the concept of INITIAL SCHEMA, supported by two SET .. INITIAL SCHEMA statements, and the CURRENT_SCHEMA can be changed with the SET SCHEMA statement.

Comment: Thank you, Fred.   I have added SET SCHEMA and SET INITIAL SCHEMA commands in the script and ran it.   It's all good until I have to SELECT from the table....   see attached log file. 

NOTE:  I can run all these commands individually in the HSQL DBManager and it works fine in the tool.

Comment: I'm including above the following files:
SimpleJobLaunchFunctionalTest.java - my test case
mock-bms-tables.sql - my db script that sets up custom tables
data-source-test-context.xml - defines my two databases that I use
batch-hsql.properties - property file for HSQL dbs

Answer (score 0):

My script (attached) shows exactly how to do it.   It's right, nothing wrong with the script or schema definition.   My problem was that my test case was refering to the wrong Jdbc template when inserting data into the CMNREF.C* table....  the correct stmt should have been:

```
jdbcTemplateBMS**.update("INSERT INTO CMNREF.CNTRCT_E
```

Also, I need to turn on the DB2 mode for my sql script to work properly